# How to land on a specific tab using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to go to a specific tab using `vuejs` and `element-ui`.
Here is the jsfiddle file. https://jsfiddle.net/hutsu1zf/10/

By default it lands to first tab. How can I land on any other tab while page load event. I am new to vuejs so even some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vue-router redirect to default path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060414/vue-router-redirect-to-default-path-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `activeName` attribute of tab. 
Look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hutsu1zf/21/

Change `activeName` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `value` attribute in `el-tabs` and the `name` in `el-tab-pane`:

```
<el-tabs type="border-card" value="2">
  <el-tab-pane   id="tab-1" label="Route">
    Route
  </el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane id="tab-0"  label="Config">
    Config
  </el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane id="tab-2" name="2" label="Role">
    Role
  </el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane id="tab-3" label="Task">
    Task
  </el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>
```